# Characterization of measurable functions mapping into banach space via simple functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

This is a statement I read in Lang's Real and Functional Analysis Chpt VI, Sec 1, M8.

M8. A map $f:X\to E$ with $E$ finite dimensional real vector space is measurable if and only if $f$ is a limit of simple functions where simple here means measurable with image a finite subset of $E$.

$\textbf{Q1:}$ If I drop $E$ finite dimenaional but banach space, does the statement still hold? If not what is the counter example?

$\textbf{Q2:}$ If $f$ is a sequence of simple functions, clearly $f$ is measurable irregardless of $E$ being finite or infinite dimensional. Under what kind of assumption on banach space, can I assure that I can approximate a measurable function by simple functions?

Comment: What kind of space is $X$ ?

Comment: @Matematleta There is no specific restriction on $X$ as topological space other than sigma algebra of $X$ must contain direct image of borel algebra of $E$. The sigma algebra on $X$ might be not totally related to topology of $X$.

Comment: These are the so-called strongly measurable functions. See the [Pettis measurablility theorem](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1938-044-02/S0002-9947-1938-1501970-8/) for a treatment.

Comment: @Matematleta Ah, Thanks for the paper.